# Create User Story using Rally-Node

Tags: node.js, rally

I'm using Rally's [rally-node](https://github.com/RallyTools/rally-node) and I'm not sure how to create a user story to a project.

```
function createUserStory() {
    console.log("creating user story");
    restApi.create({
        type: 'user story',
        data: {
            Name: 'My UserStory',
            ScheduleState: 'Defined'
        },
        fetch: ['FormattedID'],
        scope: {
            project: project,
            workspakce: workspace
        }
    }, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("error: ", error);
        } else {
            console.log('result: ', result.Object);
        }
    });
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
error:  { [Error: /user story/create: 404! body=<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Could not find web service for '/user story/create'.</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /slm/webservice/v2.0/user%20story/create. Reason:
<pre>    Could not find web service for '/user story/create'.</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>
```

Or do I need to use `add` instead? I'm able to create defects but I'm unsure how to create user stories.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try changing:

> type: 'user story',

to

> type: 'hierarchicalrequirement',